# Logic Apps and Office 365 approval email time out

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I would like to achieve the following through logic apps - office 365 approval email. If a request is approved, invoke a run book which would shutdown the virtual machine. if denied , send an an email that action was denied. This works perfect. however  the problem is , if there is no response taken by the user, the logic app just runs forever. though i can configure the timeout value i don't want this task to be running until timeout. I want to send an email to an escalation contact if there is no response received in 30 minutes . Is it possible to achieve using office 365 approval email connector in logic app? Or should i use something else like flow?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timeout in the action's settings

[image: timeout-setting-for-an-action-in-logic-app]

And after this action, you would have a parallel path with [run after](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling#customize-run-after-behavior) configured for timed out

[image: customize-run-after-setting-for-an-action-in-logic-app]